# How Solution To Limit jQuery Step By Checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

Can I limit jQuery step by checkbox? I have this code

```
$("#wizard-h-0").hide();
$("#wizard-p-0").hide();
$("#wizard-h-1").hide();
$("#wizard-p-1").hide();
$("#wizard-h-2").hide();
$("#wizard-p-2").hide();
$("#wizard-h-3").hide();
$("#wizard-p-3").hide();
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
  $("input[type=checkbox]#changedata:checked").each(function() {
    var changedata = $(this).val();
    if(changedata=="first") {
      $("#wizard-h-0").show();
      $("#wizard-p-0").show();
    } else if(changedata=="second") {
      $("#wizard-h-1").show();
      $("#wizard-p-1").show();
    } else if(changedata=="third") {
      $("#wizard-h-2").show();
      $("#wizard-p-2").show();
    } else if(changedata=="forth") {
      $("#wizard-h-3").show();
      $("#wizard-p-3").show();
    }
  });
});
```

but not work well. Can anyone help me to solve or other method library? For more details here [preview](http:////codepen.io/ivisivel/pen/jaeYPX)

Comment: what mean by limit jquery step?

Comment: no, i mean limit step by checkbox

Comment: still not get it, what is "limit step" mean? you mean shorter down the script?

Comment: @Se0ng11 if i checked first and second so just that step will show. can you understand what i mean "limit step by checkbox"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tclynk/Lyfywhy7/5/)

```
hideAllWizard();
$("#submit").on("click", function() {
   hideAllWizard();
   $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
       var changedata = $(this).val();
       if (changedata == "first") {
           $("#wizard-1").show();
       } else if (changedata == "second") {
           $("#wizard-2").show();
        } else if (changedata == "third") {
           $("#wizard-3").show();
       } else if (changedata == "forth") {
           $("#wizard-4").show();
       }
  });
});

function hideAllWizard(){
   $("#wizard-1").hide();
   $("#wizard-2").hide();
   $("#wizard-3").hide();
   $("#wizard-4").hide();
};
```